# Positioned <p> not aligning properly

Tags: css, responsive

New to CSS. Cannot seem to get these paragraphs aligned properly! This is for a responsive page at lg, md, sm screen sizes. The blue boxes are off by just a few pixels and move around when the screen size changes. Why aren't they aligning perfectly within the green boxes? Both blue and green boxes are ps.

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/pleiovn/pen/RaBqgY

```
    #p-text {
    background-color: #a1ab5f;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#p-head {
    background-color: #5fa1ab;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: First of all your html markup is not correct. Id could not be the same name for more than once. ID should be unique. And please tell us what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Ah, could be the unique ids that are causing the problem then. I'll check into that. What I'm trying to achieve is aligning #p-text in the top right corner of #p-head without spill over.

Comment: Changed the ids to classes, but still didn't fix the alignment problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you wrote your media queries wrong

this one

```
@media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 768px)
```

should be

```
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px)
```

Comment: Ah, you're the best! Thank you! That fixes the problem with the responsiveness. Still having trouble with the "head" boxes not aligning to the "text" boxes. Ideas? http://codepen.io/pleiovn/pen/RaBqgY